# Heroku deployment error of static website

Tags: php, heroku, deployment

I deployed a static html, css, JS application to heroku using a dummy php file to trick heroku. I also added a composer.json file to the root directory. I successfully deployed the website but when it's opened all the css and JS properties are lost.

Any ideas?
here is the content of my php file:

```
<?php
 include("index.html");
 ?>
```

Comment: If you're serving static content why not use the [static buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm new to heroku, can you please elaborate on what you're saying?

Comment: I mean instead of using the PHP buildpack despite not deploying a PHP app, necessitating the addition of a composer.json and PHP file just to keep Heroku happy, why don't you use the buildpack that's actually for the thing you're trying to deploy? See e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks.

Comment: $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git I used this command and then used "git push heroku master, I'm getting 404 error

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a static.json file to my root directory : {
    "root": "dist/"
  }

Answer (score 0):

Using this code will work it out.
Create a file named index.php on Github and paste this code.

```
<?php header ( 'Location:/index.html '); ?>
```

*When you want to deploy a static web page to Heroku, it asks you to build it with php. (Although this is just html and css files.)